# Android : TextView not show in TextWatcher listener

Tags: android

I want to show text in text view if condition is satisfied with equal method in Text-watcher.I have a string variable used in a method, and I would like to compare the EditText value to that variable and text view is update and if not then display the string with **wrong code**.But ui is not updated in TextWatcher.

Here is my code

```
 private final TextWatcher vesselWatcher = new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
            Log.e("beforeTextChanged  ", " here !!! ");
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            if (s.length() == 0)
            {
                txtVesselName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.e("afterTextChanged View ", " is gone !!!");
                btnPost.setClickable(false);
                btnPost.setEnabled(false);
                Log.e("afterTextChanged  ", " btnPost.setEnabled(false); !!!");
            }
            else
            {

                if(notations.contains(etxtVesselCode.getText().toString().trim()))
                {
                    Log.e("AAA strNotations ", " Match !!! = " + etxtVesselCode.getText().toString().trim());
                    String notations = etxtVesselCode.getText().toString().trim();
                    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

                    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from VesselList where Notation " + "= ? ", new String[]{notations});

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            strVesselsTypeName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("VesselsTypeName"));

                            Log.e("strVesselsTypeName ", "= " + strVesselsTypeName );

                            SharedPreferences sp;
                            sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, 0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
                            e.putString("xyz", etxtVesselCode.getText().toString().trim());
                            e.commit();

                            Log.e("Match","!!!!");
                            txtVesselName.setText(strVesselsTypeName);

                            btnPost.setClickable(true);
                            btnPost.setEnabled(true);
                            Log.e("afterTextChanged  ", " btnPost.setEnabled(true); !!!");


                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }  db.close();

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e("Not "," Match !!");
                    txtVesselName.setText("Wrong Code !!");
                    btnPost.setClickable(false);
                    btnPost.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `txtVesselName` TextView `VISIBLE` again after calling `txtVesselName.txtVesselName` when if condition is true:

```
txtVesselName. setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry its my little mistake.